# What is the reason why class variables in nested classes are not allowed in python?

Tags: python, class

Can't seem to be able to define a class level variable in a nested subclass, such as:

```
class Outer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.inner_object=self.Inner() 

    class Inner:
        static_variable = 0
        def __init__(self):
            Inner.static_variable = 1
```

I get an error stating that "Inner is not defined" in that last line of code.

Comment: `Inner` *isn't* defined, it's `Outer.Inner`. They're allowed, but you have to reference them correctly. Note the error isn't on the last line, it's on the third - give a [mre] with the traceback.

Comment: 'I get an error stating that "Inner is not defined" **in that last line of code.**' Weird, I get an error before that, on line 3.

Comment: Sorry, had an error in the code. Line 3 should have been:                     
                self.inner_object = self.Inner()

Answer (score 2):

`class` statements are tricky. They create a new temporary *namespace*, but do not define a new *scope*. Since `Inner` is not defined inside `__init__`, the name must be looked up in an enclosing scope when `__init__` is called and a value for `Inner` is needed. But the next enclosing scope is *not* the body of the `class` statement, so no definition of `Inner` is found.

The right way to reference the `Inner` class is by correctly treating it as an attribute of the `Outer` class.

```
class Outer:
   def __init__(self):
      self.inner_object = Outer.Inner()

   class Inner:
      static_variable = 0
      def __init__(self):
          Outer.Inner.static_variable = 1
```

That said, inner classes are very rarely defined in Python, because unlike in Java, there is no prohibition on defining more than one class at the top level of a module.

Comment: Thanks, That is clear now. What I found confusing is not being able to address the inner class by name inside the inner class.

Comment: Like I said, it's tricky. You don't see the same problem with nested *functions*, because a function does create a proper scope which the inner function can close over.

Answer (score 0):

- try this
- use `self.Inner()`

```
class Outer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.inner_object=self.Inner()

    class Inner:
        static_variable = 0
        def __init__(self):
            Inner.static_variable = 1
```

Comment: `Inner.__init__` has the same problem.

Comment: What kind of problem you face!

Comment: You'll see if you try to create an instance of `Outer`.